# I'd like to get a unique of a series of a dataframe while preserving its index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, concatenation, unique

I'd like to get a unique of a series of a dataframe while preserving its index:

In Particular i have an datframe with two columns:'Stock' and 'Company Name'.

I'm using the follow code:

`lot = titoli1['Stock'].unique()`

but the returns is a unique serie but i want both series value related on unique, stock, value.

Thank you in advance for youre time spented!

Comment: Say you have 500 rows... and 20 unique stock values... what rows do you want exactly? The first occurrence of the unique value?

Comment: Column 'Stock' is releted to a Ticker identification while 'company names' is releted to a Company Name. So I want unique tiker and in the same time i want the unique in company name.

Comment: The two Uniqeu series -> Stock.unique() and companyname. unique() has a different lenght. for this reason i cant concatenate this two series but i need a different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this,

```
df[~df['col'].duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Sample Input:

```
   col
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
```

Sample Output:

```
   col
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

Comment: Perfect! It is all I need !